# How to show input text value in jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

When I click on the button will be equal to the amount of`undefined` while the amount is equal to 1 in jsp page.

```jsp
<%
    String err1 = (String) request.getAttribute("err2");
    int code = 0;

    if (err1 != null){
        code = Integer.parseInt(err1);        
        System.out.println("  code  " + code);
    }
%>
<button type="button" id="btnok">ok</button>
<br />
<%if (code == 3) {%>
    <input id="txtcode" type="hidden" value="1" />
<%}%>
<br />
```

jQuery Script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnok").click(function(event) {
        var xxx = $("#txtcode").val();
        alert("xxx  1  test  + " + xxx);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that input present on the page? Debug print. What's the value of code?

Comment: use normal javaScript function document.getElementById("txtcode").value

Comment: Are you sure that the value of the variable code is 3? Because unless it happens, you can't get the value of #txtCode. You can check if your jquery is working by adding that code right nest of button next (outside if that is)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse to set value in input, try EL instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnok").on('click', function(event) {
    alert($("#txtcode").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnok">ok</button>
<input id="txtcode" type="hidden" value="${err2}" /> <!-- `${err2}` picks the attribute value -->
```